# Python import error: cannot import name 'six' from 'sklearn.externals'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, python-import, six

I'm using numpy and mlrose, and all i have written so far is:

```
import numpy as np
import mlrose
```

However, when i run it, it comes up with an error message:

```
 File "C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mlrose\neural.py", line 12, in <module>
    from sklearn.externals import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'sklearn.externals' (C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\__init__.py)
```

Any help on sorting this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `pip install six` should install `six` and solve the problem

Comment: That isn't the issue. `mlrose` is trying to import `six` from `sklearn`, you will still get this error if you have `six` installed.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

#### Solution: The real answer is that the dependency needs to be changed by the `mlrose` maintainers.

#### A workaround is:

```
import six
import sys
sys.modules['sklearn.externals.six'] = six
import mlrose
```

Comment: Newer version of mlrose with dependency fixed is now mlrose-hiive: https://pypi.org/project/mlrose-hiive/ or https://github.com/hiive/mlrose

Comment: This solution worked for me with another package, skrules, giving the same error.

Comment: mlrose-hiive does not work on the tutorials.  Specifically simulated_annealing in the very first tutorial does not work in the fork. The dependency may be fixed, but he broke the original without talking about it in any documentation I've found.

Comment: I made an issue for it https://github.com/gkhayes/mlrose/issues/59

Comment: This also works for the SkopeRules package.

Answer (score 2):

`from sklearn.externals import six` is deprecated, use `import six` instead

Comment: Doesn't seem like a very helpful response, unless you think @Jack here is a developer of `mlrose` (I definitely didn't get the sense from his question that he is).

Comment: Yeah, relatively new to mlrose so I wouldn’t know what to do there

Comment: This solution worked for me. Scikit-garden had the line `from sklearn.externals import six` and I changed it to import six. Seems to work fine now.