# Override import from a library

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn, six

I am using a python library that imports a deprecated library. One way to fix this is to change the library source to fix this error (e.g., `import six` - see [Python import error: cannot import name 'six' from 'sklearn.externals'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61867945/python-import-error-cannot-import-name-six-from-sklearn-externals) ), but I don't want to do this because it means that I need to have a customized version of the library inside my project.

I would like to know if it is possible to set the PYTHONPATH, or add any line in my project to override the import used in the library.

```
from sklearn.externals import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'sklearn.externals
```

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you linked provides your workaround and what line you need to override the import.

Comment: See Cireo’s answer. Also, why don’t you [`import six`](https://github.com/benjaminp/six) directly, instead of fetching a reference from another module?

Comment: @Jens I believe they don't care about importing `six`, they are trying to use a library which has bad references (likely part of the py27 unsupported apocalypse).