# i got this error on spyder ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'sklearn.externals' despite i have installed the six module

Tags: python, import, importerror, six

File "C:\Users\Baha cherni\Desktop\python\tp\tp22222.py", line 7, in 
from sklearn.externals import six

ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'sklearn.externals' (C:\Users\Baha cherni\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals_*init*_.py)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `sklearn.externals.six` is deprecated, you can try importing six with `import six`. Similar question is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61867945/python-import-error-cannot-import-name-six-from-sklearn-externals).