# What is the difference between the mlrose project and mlose-hiive?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't find the difference between the mlrose (https://pypi.org/project/mlrose/) project and mlrose-hiive (https://pypi.org/project/mlrose-hiive/). I know hiive has some kind of extensions compared to the original mlrose but I can't find some documentation or anything that explains the new features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accordign private training forum info where I have access, it seems mlrose-hiive:

- mostly are improvements and fixes some dependency bugs, as in the six package: [Python import error: cannot import name 'six' from 'sklearn.externals'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61867945/python-import-error-cannot-import-name-six-from-sklearn-externals),
- is backwards-compatible, so, mlrose readthedocs should be OK, they even recommend that in the project repo readme (https://github.com/hiive/mlrose).

Also: https://pypi.org/project/mlrose-hiive/

Therefore, documentation in https://mlrose.readthedocs.io/en/stable/